# Need Regular Expression for below values to enter in textbox

Tags: jquery

I need some regex that will match only numbers that are decimal to two places after that comma. For example

123, 12.12, 1.00, 899.33 = match

12.123 = not match

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: jquery is not the correct tag for this 'question'. In fact this isn't a question at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: `^[\+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

- `^` and `$` makes sure that the entire string must be a match
- `[\+|-]?` allows a + or - or nothing in front of the expression
- `\d+` makes sure at least one digit (including 0) is in front of the decimal point. use `*` if you want to allow notations like `.25` or `-.2`
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` is the decimal portion the ? at the end makes it optional. if you do put a decimal point in, then `\d{1,2}` must follow. this is one or two digits
- the `?:` in the regex group `(...)` indicates that it is a non-capturing group. this is (probably) not required, but it can help later on when wanting to use groups and not wanting to deal with groups, that you don't need numbers assigned to, taking up the numbers.

You can design and test regular expressions at [this helpful size](https://www.debuggex.com/)

Comment: it's not working   123, 12.12, 1.00, 899.33 = match or 123,45.11,345,43.00 = match both way should match

Comment: @Ankushreddy please be more clear. all your examples match. the regular expression matches any number with 0, 1 or 2 decimal places and with period `.` as the decimal point, as you have requested. what number does not match but should, or which string matches but shouldn't?